# jquery fadein is flickering

Tags: jquery, css, menu, css-position

I'm hoping someone can help me please. I have the following problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/zhPAF/

Mark-up:

```
<nav>
                <ul id="topNav">
                    <li id="topNavFirst"><a href="pages/about/about.php" id="aboutNav">About Us</a></li>
                    <li id="topNavSecond"><a href="pages/people/our-people.php" id="peopleNav">Our People</a>
                        <ul id="subList1">
                            <li><a href="pages/people/mike-hadfield.php">Mike Hadfield</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/karen-sampson.php">Karen Sampson</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/milhana-farook.php">Milhana Farook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/kim-crook.php">Kim Crook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/amanda-lynch.php">Amanda Lynch</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/gideon-scott.php">Gideon Scott</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/paul-fuller.php">Paul Fuller</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/peter-chaplain.php">Peter Chaplain</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/people/laura-hutley.php">Laura Hutley</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="serviceNavDropdown"><a href="our-services.php" id="servicesNav">Our Services</a>
                        <ul id="subList2">
                            <li><a href="pages/services/company-and-commercial.php">Company &amp; Commercial</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/services/employment.php">Employment</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/services/civil-litigation.php">Civil Litigation</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/services/debt-recovery.php">Debt Recovery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/services/conveyancing.php">Conveyancing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/services/commercial-property.php">Commerical Property</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/services/wills-and-probate.php">Wills &amp; Probate</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/services/family.php">Matrimonial &amp; Family</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="pages/news/news.php" id="newsNav">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/careers/careers.php" id="careersNav">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages/contact/contact.php" id="contactNav">Contact</a></li>
                </ul><!-- /topNav -->
            </nav>​
```

CSS

```
#topNav {
float:right;
height:30px;
margin:0;
font-size:12px;
}

#topNav li {
display:inline;
list-style:none;
color:#666;
border-left: 1px solid #666;
padding: 0 0 0 3px;
}

#topNav li a:hover {
}

#topNavFirst {
border-left: 1px solid transparent !important;
}

#topNav ul{
background:#fff url(images/people-ul-bg.png) no-repeat;
border:1px solid #666;
border-top:0px solid transparent;
border-bottom:2px solid #666;
list-style:none;
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
width:90px;
text-align:left;
padding:5px 0 5px 0px;
z-index:10;
}

#topNav ul li{
display:block;
border-left:0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
padding:0;
}

#topNav ul a{
padding:0 0 0 5px;    
}

#topNav li:hover ul{
left:auto;
margin-left:55px;
margin-top:-1px;            
}

#topNav li:hover a { 
color:#369;
}

#topNav li:hover ul a{ 
text-decoration:none;
color:#666;
}

#topNav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
color:#fff;;
width:100%;
}

#topNav ul li:hover {
background:#369;
display: block;
}

#topNav ul li a {
display: block;
padding:0 0 0 4px;
}

#serviceNavDropdown ul{ 
background:#fff url(images/service-ul-bg.png) no-repeat;
width:135px !important;
margin-left:117px !important;
margin-top:-1px;        
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $('#subList1').css("display", "none");
        $('#topNavSecond').hover(function () {
            $('#subList1').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $('#subList1').fadeOut('slow');
        });
         $('#subList2').css("display", "none");
        $('#serviceNavDropdown').hover(function () {
            $('#subList2').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $('#subList2').fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });​
```

When the #topNavSecond ('Our People') anchor is hovered the ul #subList1 should fade in. Now as you can see from the fiddle it's not fading on the first hover but only on subsequent hovers. Similarly the next anchor ('Our Services') is doing the same and there is some fading issues when going between them.

I've reached the limits of my knowledge of jquery (which admittedly isn't much!) and would dearly appreciate some help.

edit>
The code above is the corrected code and is working. But the following jQuery is better, adding some .stop(true, true):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        $('#subList1').css("display", "none");
        $('#topNavSecond').hover(function () {
            $('#subList1').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $('#subList1').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        });
         $('#subList2').css("display", "none");
        $('#serviceNavDropdown').hover(function () {
            $('#subList2').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $('#subList2').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
```

Comment: jsFiddle is a great tool on this site but you also need to make your question more "self-contained". Otherwise, when the jsFiddle site goes down, the question is useless.

Comment: Really sorry Sparky, i'll include the code in the op.

Answer (score 2):

You have it set `$('#topNavSecond').parent().hover(function ()` #topNavSecond's parent would be the entire UL. I believe you mean  `$('#topNavSecond').hover(function ()`

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zhPAF/1/

Comment: Wow! Thats was a quick response and it works perfectly, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any flickering but maybe I'm not understanding.  However you should add some `.stop()`s before the animation happens in case it isn't finished.

```
        $('#subList1').css("display", "none");
        $('#topNavSecond').parent().hover(function () {
            $('#subList1').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $('#subList1').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        });
         $('#subList2').css("display", "none");
        $('#serviceNavDropdown').parent().hover(function () {
            $('#subList2').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function(){
            $('#subList2').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/zhPAF/3/

Comment: Good thoughts here. See @MoDFox answer as well. `parent()` is used where it shouldn't. Perhaps combine answers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would do some additions to your css:
Add this to this:

```
#topNav li {
    position:relative;
}
```

Add this rule:

```
#topNav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

Now instead of calling things directly, grab them with jQuery by their tag type and hierarchy:

```
$('#topNav li').hover(function () {
            $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).animate({'opacity' : 'show'}, 'slow');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).animate({'opacity' : 'hide'}, 'slow');
        });
```

This will work on any ul contained within an li inside anything id'd as topnav.  Use CSS to dictate the positioning. I went with animate because it functions the same and offers you some more control... you could easily add 'height' : 'show' and 'height' : 'hide' to it to get a nice animation going.

I would advise against setting specific widths to the ul's inside the li's.  Add a white-space: nowrap; to the li's and then do it all at the a tag level using some padding, the ul's and li's will shape to these.

Also, I would avoid using :hover on anything but an a, as IE doesn't play well with it otherwise.